# How can I use lang class laravel in vue.js 2?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.3, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-bg">
        <li role="presentation" v-for="item in tabs">
            1. failed -> {{ item.name }} 2.success -> {{trans('purchase.payment.tab')}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tabs: [
                    {name: "trans('purchase.payment.tab')"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My lang in laravel(resources/lang/en/purchase.php) like this :

```
<?php
return [
    'payment' => [
        'tab' => 'Payment Status',
    ],
    ...
];
```

If the component vue executed, the result like this :

> 1. failed -> trans('purchase.payment.tab') 2.success -> Payment Status

So, if trans used in data, it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can use vue-i18n in this case

Comment: @Hanlin Wang, What do you mean? Try to explain in more detail

Comment: Can you post your feedback for us, @SuccessMan? =)

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to use a PHP helper inside JavaScript. But, you can create an object of translations.

In your `AppServiceProvider` (you can create a new one if you want):

```
// Don't forget to import the facade
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;


public function boot() {
    $translations = [
     'auth' => Lang::get('auth'),
     'pagination' => Lang::get('pagination'),
     'passwords' => Lang::get('passwords'),
     'validation' => Lang::get('validation'),
   ];

   view()->share('translations', json_encode($translations));

}
```

In your HTML (I suggest header) you can just call:

```
window.app = {
    translations: {!! $translations !!},
}
```

And to access using in JS, you can just do this, for example:

```
this.app.translations.auth.throttle // Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n) for that. That way you should make its own dictionary.
I made a `i18n/en.js` file;

```
module.exports = {
    login: {
      title: 'Login',
      loginButton: 'Login',
      emailInput: 'email',
      passwordInput: 'password',
    },
    Form: {
      title: 'Form',
    }
}
```

and a `i18n/hu.js` with the same variables in Hungarian. Then I made a `i18n/map.js` file:

```
var en = require('./en.js');
var hu = require('./hu.js');

module.exports = {
  en,
  hu,
}
```

and finally, set it in `vue.js`, check my `app.js` file part:

```
require('./bootstrap'); // vue comes from here
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import dictionary from './i18n/map'

var localeTmp = document.documentElement.lang;
var locale = "hu";
if(localeTmp) {
  locale = localeTmp
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: locale, // set locale
  dictionary, // set map of dictionary
})
....
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    i18n,
});
```

Its a very elegant way.

and how I use in component? simple:

```
  ....
  <md-input-container>
    <md-icon>person</md-icon>
    <label>{{ $t("loginForm.emailInput") }}</label>
    <md-input email name="email" required v-model="email" />
  </md-input-container>
  ....
```