# Internalization, languages files and administration

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a project built on `vue` which uses `v-i18n` to manage all the language and caption in a website.

All the languages are then stored into `.js` files

#### Situation

There will probably have a lot of changes to do over time.

#### Question

I'm wondering what could be the best to let one (besides a developer) easily manage that.

I was thinking about an admin interface link to a database but since `vue-i18n` relies on file I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469501/5349795) on a older question.

I think this is one of the elegant way to handle the i18n. You should made a map of dictionary (as I did, where you can define all the languages), then you should handle just that one map at the `app.js` where the vue is defined.

I hope it can help you. If you have any question just write a comment ;)