# how to view multi lang in vue + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization

I have completed translation for Vue. I have 2 languages, EN & MS. Default would be in EN. How do I route the web link to view in MS? For standard Laravel page, I will add `?lang=en` or `?lang=ms` at the end of the link. How about Vue? Do I need to declare anything in blade file?

Comment: Create a locale switcher in the header nav. If you are working on a single page application in multi lang. Check this starter template which would be a perfect fit. Or check the code how it plays with translations so that you can get the basic idea.https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa

Answer (score 0):

get the lang parameter using `window.location`, then store that in the browser:

```
localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
```

to retrieve it later use:

```
var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you the [vue-i18n](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/introduction.html) lib for handling the multi language.

There is [my older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464035/how-can-i-use-lang-class-laravel-in-vue-js-2/46469501#46469501) how can you use this lib.